# Why were new parts added to a question by "community" months after the original was answered?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, editing, suggested-edits

In March 2014, the question
[Find the Nash equilibria for a joint project modeled as a strategic game](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/724029/139123)
was migrated here from MathOverflow.
It was promptly answered and the OP accepted the answer.

In February 2015 (a few hours ago as I write this),
an anonymous user proposed an edit that appended three more sentences
(each of which was a question) to the end of the original question text.

The added questions were relevant to the original problem and might even
have made sense to include in the problem when originally posted.
At this time I would find it completely reasonable to ask a new question
as a followup to the old question.
It just seems a little weird to have a question extended in this way; I think it makes
it appear as if the long-standing accepted answer ignored several parts of the question.

Possibly I'm overthinking this.
As far as I know, quite possibly the edit is perfectly fine.
But are there guidelines for this sort of thing?

Comment: The real question is: why did this edit [get approved](http://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/354713)?

Comment: I did notice it was a split vote (2 to 1). If I knew an obviously appropriate place to ask someone individually about their vote on an edit I probably would have done that before (possibly instead of) asking here.

Comment: You can always roll back the edit.

Comment: I'm sensing two votes for "you're overthinking this" ...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Apparently, some anonymous visitor faced the same or a similar problem, and tried to ask their follow-up questions by editing them into the question. Such an edit is invalid and should  be rejected.

I took this as an opportunity to polish the title and tags, along with removing the extraneous bits from the question.

Comment: A better edit than I probably would have done. So a happy ending after all.